# Data not fully displaying on bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

For some reason the data on my bar chart is not displaying.

I am using charts.js

The html code is:

```
  <div class="chart-wrapper">
     <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script>
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
let colorHex = ['#870000', '#000f61', '#004f03'];
var barChartData = {
    labels: ['Specialist1', 'Specialist2', 'Specialist3'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        borderColor: '#FF0000',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [10, 12, 7]
        },{
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        borderColor: '#00FF00',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [9, 8, 5]
        }]
    };
        
        

let myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Cases Referred vs Cases Solved'
        }
    }
})
    </script>
```

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97kUm.png)

Any ideas why the second dataset for specialist 3 is not loading? Also why are the values randomly dotted around?

Comment: Hey! Try adding to your `data` prop only your `barChartData` var, like: `data: barChartData`

Comment: This works - however i now have a new issue - I have updated the question would be great if you could have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because the y axis start at 5.

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
let colorHex = ['#870000', '#000f61', '#004f03'];
var barChartData = {
  labels: ['Specialist1', 'Specialist2', 'Specialist3'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Dataset 1',
    borderColor: '#FF0000',
    borderWidth: 2,
    data: [10, 12, 7]
  }, {
    label: 'Dataset 2',
    borderColor: '#00FF00',
    borderWidth: 2,
    data: [9, 8, 5]
  }]
};



let myChart2 = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: barChartData,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Cases Referred vs Cases Solved'
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="chart-wrapper">
  <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
```